# The relation between spin and momentum in particle state

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, group-theory, quantum-states

In quantum field theory, it seems that when we consider a massive particle's spin degree of freedom, we usually do in the particle's rest frame. And I know the little group will only change spin DOF and leave the momentum unchanged. My question is:

If there is a Lorentz transformation that only change the momentum of the particle and leave spin DOF unchanged? And how to determine that transformation? Or in other words, can we compare spin of particles in different momentum?

I think there should have, because when we transform a particle to its rest frame, the transformation operator is not unique since we can always do a more little group transformation, so there should be a unique one to leave the spin unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Pauli, Encyclopedia of Physics or his book General principles of Quantum theory p. 168

Bottom line: The relativistic generators of current transport in 2-planes $(i,k)\in (x,y,z)$ are the

$$\mathbf P_{ik} = x_i (p_k - \frac{e}{c} A_k) - x_k (p_i - \frac{e}{c} A_i) + \frac{\hbar}{2 i} \alpha^i \ \alpha ^k $$

Any measurable distinction of orbital and spin parts does not exist in relativistc quantum theory.

The same problem exists in relativistic classical mechanics of spinning rigid bodies. A relativistic invariant definition of center of gravitation, orbital momentum and spin is arbitrary.

Its a gauge problem, because a Lorentz transformation changes the split of space time into a time-indexed 3-space for the representation in Hilbert spaces and the spin basis is arbitrary by the principles.

The quantum low energy non-relativistic limit with its fixed Galilean Pauli spin basis p. 169 (22.4) produces the famous spin corrections to the trivial energy split by $\sigma . H$, the Thomas precession
$$(E\times (p-e /c A) )\cdot \sigma$$

in the eletric field (moving wrt to E induces a virtual H) and the Darwin term

$$E \cdot (p-e /c A) $$

classically work by transport against force.